# How to set Highcharts xAxis position on the yAxis zero value (negative/positive chart)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to have my xAxis not below my chart but in the middle (**on the yAxis zero value**).

And I would like also to have the xAxis labels :

- **above the xAxis** when it is a **negavite** value
- **below the xAxis** when it is a **positive** value

[image: Wanted chart]

Here is what I have : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kn9h/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
                    showFirstLabel : true,
                    showLastLabel : true,
                    type : "category",
                    tickLength : 0,
                    lineWidth : 2
            },

        series: [{
            data: [
                {name : 'T1', y: 123},{name : 'T2', y: 152},{name : 'T3', y: -120},{name : 'T4', y: 0},{name : 'T5', y: 142},{name : 'T6', y: 212}
            ],
            type : 'column'
        }]
    });
});
```

- **Does it exist an easy way to do this ?**
- If not, how to do this ?

Thanks.

---

### Solution :

Thanks to Pawel Fus (thanks, thanks, thanks), here is the solution for my problem : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kn9h/3/).

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                load: function () {
                                        var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
                    var serie = this.series[0];

                    for (var current_tick in xAxis.ticks) {
                        var tick = xAxis.ticks[current_tick];

                        if(serie.data[current_tick]){
                            if (serie.data[current_tick].y > 0) {
                                tick.label.attr({
                                    y: tick.label.y + 18
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
                    showFirstLabel : true,
                    showLastLabel : true,
                    type : "category",
                    tickLength : 0,
                    crossing:0,
                    opposite:true,
                    lineWidth : 2
            },

        series: [{
            data: [
                {name : 'T1', y: 123},{name : 'T2', y: 152},{name : 'T3', y: -120},{name : 'T4', y: 0},{name : 'T5', y: 142},{name : 'T6', y: 212}
            ],
            type : 'column'
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers for you:

1. Yes, this is possible by using [Highcharts plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values) for that.
2. This is not supported, you can use `chart.events.load` to loop over all labels in xAxis and update their position according to value in first series for respective category

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try the plugin. Then I'm gonna change the label position in chart.events.load if there is no other way.

Comment: In label formatter you can also try to update label y-position, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: It is possible to update the label y-position in label formatter ? I thought it was only to format text. Actually, I've used this feature only to format date.

Comment: Just checked, sorry for promising comment, it's not possible. Regarding my first answer, see how to update dataLabels: http://jsfiddle.net/9e8NS/ - something similar could be easily done for axis.labels.

Comment: Ths thing is that if I know how to change properties of each dataLabels, **but** I don't know how to change properties of each xAxis.labels... I've got : `this.series[0].xAxis` and then what ? Thanks for your help (I have done a console.log of this object but it doesn't help me more).

Comment: Well.. live example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9e8NS/1/ - let me know if something is not clear ;)

Comment: Great ! Thanks. It was not easy to find this solution.