# Is it possible to change properties of xAxis.labels individually in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to set **different properties for my labels on the xAxis** ([Here is my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683223/how-to-set-highcharts-xaxis-position-on-the-yaxis-zero-value-negative-positive/20683479?noredirect=1#comment30975054_20683479)).

I know how to do this for `dataLabels` : [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.dataLabels).

It is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648835/1788704).

---

But I don't find anything to do the same thing for `xAxis.labels`.

**Does it exist a way to do this ?**

---

---

### Solution :

It changes only `y` property of `xAxis labels`.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kn9h/3/).

```
  chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                                    var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
                var serie = this.series[0];

                for (var current_tick in xAxis.ticks) {
                    var tick = xAxis.ticks[current_tick];

                    if(serie.data[current_tick]){
                        if (serie.data[current_tick].y > 0) {
                            tick.label.attr({
                                y: tick.label.y + 18
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to do that.

What I would probably do in this situation is create to x axes, one for the positive values, and one for the negative.

{{edit - although, it seems the axis offset plugin only works (at least from what I am seeing) if you have opposite: true set for the axis.

SO, you have to offset the labels on one of them.  `example`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/S48eX/

Comment: Thanks, but I have found a solution that generates more easily  a chart : http://jsfiddle.net/3kn9h/3/

Comment: There is no way of setting different options for each label, only for all of them.